# When is it appropriate to include javascript in your html vs an external .js?

Tags: javascript, html

It looks like it's not unusual to have  tags in your html but wouldn't it be neater to have all js in an external file that is then referenced in the html? 
Does it differ in applications? Is it more messy to have a tonnes of lines linking to lots of js files?

Comment: You would have just a single `bundle.js` and maybe a couple of libraries from CDN's if you are bundling your code with something like webpack. No mess at all.

Comment: I agree with @JakeWeary bundling your external files ftw. This also may apply to your stylesheets.

Comment: This must be a duplicate, but I can't find previous ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Inlining JavaScript**

- Pro: No need for additional HTTP requests, therefore potentially faster initial loading.
- Con: Cannot cache JavaScript independently of HTML, therefore potentially unnecessary code download on consecutive visits.
- Con: (related to the previous point) All the JavaScript code might have to be downloaded every time, because HTML files are usually not cached (but that might depend on your server settings).
- Con: Cannot share code across HTML pages.

**External JavaScript files**

- Pro: Can cache JavaScript files independently of other resources.
- Pro: Can share JavaScript code across multiple HTML pages.
- Con: The more external JavaScript files, the more HTTP requests have to be mode, the longer it takes to load the page (on first load at least). This can be mitigated by bundling JavaScript files together. E.g. bundling files that change infrequently for long term caching into a single file and bundle all files into another file.

Answer (score 3):

Both work, here are some pros and cons of external files...

Pros:

1. You can compartmentalize your code. This is especially useful when you might have a main JavaScript file, and then a few small bits of JavaScript to do different unrelated things
2. It makes version control easier
3. By putting code in separate files, it is easier to find exactly where a certain bit is

Cons:

1. External files means more file requests, decreasing speed
2. Entire files can be unnecessary for small bits of code
3. It is easier to control exactly when the script is executed by inlining it

Just a note that for scripts that need to execute at the end of the page (as in where you'd put a `<script>` right before the end `</body>` tag), you can use this instead:

```
<script src="myscript.js" defer></script>
```

Personally, I generally prefer to put code in separate files, as I find it easier to manage, but see the pros and cons above to make your decision.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the implication, you want to optimize speed. For example, if you have a few pages that require light javascript it would be a lot faster to have some `<script>...</script>` tags rather than an external file.

On the other hand, if you have a lot of complex algorithms/processes that need to be done on many pages, it would be easier on your pages' performance and load speed to fetch the information from an external file, rather than having the page load the hundreds of lines of code you need.

Comment: *"it would be a lot faster"* What is "it" here?

Comment: Clearly, the "it" is towards the speed of the page. `It`'s not rocket science.

Comment: Not so clear IMO. You could also refer to development time (dumping everything into a single file is faster than creating multiple files and linking them).

Answer (score 1):

Really depends on the size of your app.

- Few lines of code? Put it between script tags.
- Small project? Referencing external files is fine.
- Bigger/production-level? You'll need a module bundler - look up **webpack**.

Answer (score 0):

From my small experience, people used to separate HTML and JS. Recently there's a move to combining them together. I think they separated them because of separation of concerns, but HTML and JS aren't really different 'concerns'; HTML is the nouns and JS is the verbs. This move has, at least in part, been facilitated by [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

So to answer your question, when is it appropriate, that's going to be very opinionated but I can see a world where HTML and JS are always combined and life could be good as long as the file sizes are small and manageable.

Comment: People used to toss HTML (markup), styles, and javascript all together in one file, scattered throughout the file, and copy-pasted all over their pages. Making a change or fixing a bug was a total nightmare, because you had to hunt down _everywhere_ those bits were repeated. Then they learned. Separate concerns, build re-usable pieces; a change is made in one place, and it's fixed everywhere because code & styles are shared. **Now** people are forgetting that (again) and going _back_ to throwing everything together in the same pot, copy-pasting themselves to death again.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to everything else mentioned already, there are two occasions where I use inline `<script>` tags. I only do this when I cannot find an alternative solution or the alternative is cumbersome.

One case is when I need to set a `javascript` variable based on the evaluation of php code. An example would be on a page refresh when data has been changed - I set a `Javascript` "dirty" flag so I can give a warning if the user attempts to exit the page without saving:

```
if ($dataHasChanged){
    echo "<script>dirtyFlag.value = true;</script>";
}
```

Another example is when running php code in an `iframe` where I wish to return the result of the php code (either to a parent element or to set a javascript variable):

```
    $result = updateDb($data);
    if ($result === false) {
        echo "<script> document.write( parent.document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Error')</script>";
    }
```